# Event data storage with InfluxDB

Tags: database, time-series, influxdb

I’m working on a new project that will involve storing events from various systems at random intervals.  Events such as deployment completions,  production bugs, continuous integration events etc. This is somewhat time series data, although the volume should be relatively low,  a few thousand a day etc.

I had been thinking maybe InfluxDB was a good option here as the app will revolve mostly around plotting time lines and durations etc,  although there will need to be a small amount of data stored with these datapoints.  Information like error messages ,  descriptions , url and maybe twitter sized strings.    I would say that there is a good chance most events will not actually have a numerical value but more just act as a point in time reference for an event.

As an example, I would expect a lot of events to look like (in Influx line protocol format)

`events,stream=engineering,application=circleci,category=error message="Web deployment failure - Project X failed at step 5", url=“https://somelink.com”,value=0`

My question here is,  am I approaching this wrong?  Is InfluxDB the wrong choice for this type of data? I have read a few horror stories about data corruption and i’m a bit nervous there but i’m not entirely sure of any better (but also affordable) options.

How would you go about storing this type of data in a way that can can accessed at a high frequency for a purpose such as a realtime dashboard?
Im resisting the urge to just rollout a Postgres database.

Comment: This sounds more like a log-oriented app? Use Elastic?

Comment: Hmm maybe. isn't it better to have a DB backed Elastic instance though? Like postgres backing it?